# Shopify Product/update webhook firing on inventory change

Tags: shopify

I have registered to shopify's product webhook using topic `product/update`. As per answer of a shopify staff memeber here:

https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/Does-the-product-update-webhook-let-me-know-if-an-item-has-been/m-p/500638/highlight/true#M32428

product/update webhook should not fire when there is a change in inventory level, but i am observing a completely different behavior, when ever a product is sold that fire `product/update` webhook.

Has anyone else experienced same issue? or i am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be as simple as in that shop, when a product sells, another App you have no idea about, changes the product for some reason. Plenty of Apps could do that. And when they do change the product, it is updated, and you get a webhook for product/update, triggered by a sale.

Of course, you can also dream up other scenarios where things change.

Following is an answer by shopify staff member:

https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/Does-the-product-update-webhook-let-me-know-if-an-item-has-been/m-p/518566/highlight/true#M33787

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi David thanks for your time. You are right but i am testing it on my development store and there are no other apps installed :(

Comment: It is too bad there is no summary in the webhook payload showing the differences between the product before and after, which would provide for a quick answer as to why it was sent.

Comment: I suppose for you the best and coolest thing to do, is record the JSON of a product BEFORE you sell it, and then the JSON of the product AFTER you sell it, and do a quick diff on the two. Whatever jumps out will explain the reason. And you can share that knowledge with everyone here, and also perhaps make a legitimate complaint to Shopify!

Comment: i will do that shortly. My observation is that each order alters the product quantity and that in turn triggers `product/update` hook

Comment: By any chance you know if there is away i can limit number of fields for which `update` hook fires on product/product-variants ?

Comment: When you create a webhook subscription, you can include an optional fields attribute with just the fields you are interested in seeing. I doubt this will help you though.

Comment: Thanks. I though in fields attribute we can specify those fields for which we want to track changes?

Comment: Thanks for your time David i have edited your answer to include some more information i got from shopify support. I think that completes your answer and might help someone in future. Regards.

Comment: Good to see the whole issue is exposed. Hope you can solve your computing issue moving forward by getting rid of the product update webhook and use the more appropriate one for your actual needs!